# Overriding the save method for all the models in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I want to override the save method for all the models in my application. It can be easily done by using inheritance

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    def save(*args, **kwargs):
        if some_condition:
             return

        super().save(args, kwargs)

class User(MyModel):
      ....
```

The problem with this approach is that this will need a change in the already defined models. Also, models defined in the external libraries will also need to be taken care of separately.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I think you can do that in django forms or serializers whatever you are using by overriding the default save method

Comment: have you looked at the pre_save or post_save Signals?

Comment: Pre-save can't be used because I need to skip the save if some condition is satisfied. Updated the question.

Comment: you can use a mixin and define a `save` method there and then inherit that mixin in every Model.

Comment: Can you add an example of exactly what you want this save method to look like?

Comment: @IainShelvington I want to update the row only when there is a change in any of the field.

Comment: @rishabh_gupta how are you determining when there is a change and why do you want to do this? Please add an example `save` method. You could monkey patch the `Model` class but you will probably break a lot of things you don't intend to, `DateTimeField`s with `auto_now=True` for example